# Restrict SQL Query to SELECT operation ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2016

We are creating a UI for users to 
1) Run Select statements on the database (Query can include Join or subquery) 
2) View the result in the same screen

Right now we are checking if the input string has any of the following keywords  INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/TRUNCATE/CREATE/ALTER/DROP/GRANT/REVOKE statements and also executing the query under SQL user which has only SELECT permission on the DB.

Is there any other way to add an extra layer of protection to validate the query before executing it under reading only user?

Thanks

Comment: Basically, don't let users run any query that want to write! You're going to regret it....

Comment: Due to the business requirement, we were unable to avoid this situation. So I am trying to find the best way to avoid any potential security related issue. This tool will be deployed only on the pre-prod environment, so the level of risk is comparatively low.

Comment: You can do that by using transaction. if you get any affected rows, rollback transaction. I checked for triggers (i.e. if any trigger is applied on any operation on table), the effect of trigger will also be rolled back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure parameters are used for providing input to the select
   statements (avoid SQL injection). Although a user with SELECT only
   permission will anyway not able to execute, but this will also
   ensure that input is sane.
2. Ensure that any database related
   errors are not output directly on screen

Comment: User will input the whole query in the same UI including the parameter in WHERE clause. So we will not be able to break down into parameters to query.

Comment: Sure, I will ensure that all the errors are logged in table and extact error message is not displayed in UI.

Answer (score 0):

I assume not all application users are valid database users too.

You need to have 2 database logins created. One should just have `db_datareader` permission which should be used to run queries. In your code handle the `SqlException` to see if end user tried to execute another statement apart from a select.

There should be another database login which application code should use to perform any other DML operation.

Comment: Thanks, we are also using the 2 login approach now. The second user account will be used store the query on the table and retrieve later.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting people write anything they want as a command and just checking the command for some words you think could be harmful, why don't you create a 'query generator' that can have only one action (select), from t tables (where t is the number of available tables), and with the desired columns. You could add some drop down with the available actions (select in your case), available tables and available columns. This way you generate the query yourself with the given inputs, without letting the user directly write commands to your server.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. This approach was rejected because it was getting complicated as the query might include several join and subquery. Also, the user was comfortable in writing the query by themselves instead of designer based approach. So we ended up providing an option to copy/paste the query.